# Isomorphism Between Union of two subspaces and Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

**Prove that for two subspaces 1,2 of a finite dimensional vector space V , 1+2 is isomorphic to 1$\bigoplus$2  if and only if $1 \cap 2 = {0}$.**

I know how to show the statement that "$=1 \bigoplus 2$  if and only if $=1+2$ and $1 \cap 2={0}$."(1) But this statement (1) does not seem to be equivalent to the above statement that I need to prove. So to show isomorphism, I need to show bijection between sum and direct sum and dimensions equal.

Since $\dim(U1+U2)=\dim(U1)+\dim(U2)-\dim(U1 \cap U2)=\dim(U1)+\dim(U2)$, we need to show bijection which I am a bit stuck on.

Or is there an easier way to just prove this using (1)?

Comment: You have been around for more than three yearss. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: edited the whole thing again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this from statement (1): Let $W = U_1 + U_2$. Then $U_1$ and $U_2$ are both subspaces of $W$ (even if $W$ isn't all of $V$), because certainly $U_1$ and $U_2$ are both contained in $W$.

Statement (1), with $W$ playing the role of $V$, says that "$W = U_1 \oplus U_2$ if and only if $W = U_1 + U_2$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = 0$".

In this case, we know $W = U_1 + U_2$, because we defined it that way. So this statement simplifies to "$U_1 + U_2 = U_1 \oplus U_2$ if and only if $U_1 \cap U_2 = 0$", which was what you wanted to show.

Comment: how do the two statements lead to my statement?

Comment: How do which two statements lead to which of your statements?

Comment: thats genius my only question is how did we define that W=V=U1+U2, we did not define it in the question that V=U1+U2

Comment: The letter $V$ is just a name. We are not redefining the $V$ in the question; we are applying statement (1) with a different space ($U_1 + U_2$) where it uses $V$.

Comment: but the question is "two subspaces 1,2 of a finite dimensional vector space V ," which implies that V is the entire space here and we did not define U1, U2 to be s.t. U1+U2=V. Am I right to assume that the V you're using here would be more appropriate if we use something like V'?

Comment: actually, sorry my bad, i think i am confused because of how i phrased the question myself so basically the statement holds even if U1+U2 does not span the whole V space? if so, please disregard my above question

Comment: Instead of your statement (1), let's take the statement "$W = U_1 \oplus U_2$ if and only if $W = U_1 + U_2$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = 0$". No mention of $V$ here at all, so now there is no conflict with the $V$ in the question. The idea is that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of $V$, but they're also subspaces of $U_1 + U_2$.

Answer (score 0):

They are essentialy the same, you dont even have to use the statement you cited,

If $U_{1} + U_{2}$ is isomorphic to $U_{1} \bigoplus U_{2}$ of course $U_{1} \cap U_{2}  = \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ since the isomorphism is injective you know that only the null vector lies in the intersection.

For the other implication as you showed since the dim $U_{1} + U_{2}$ = dim $U_{1} \bigoplus U_{2}$ thanks to the non intersecting hypothesis, we know that exists some isomorphism between those two spaces thanks to the complete invariancy of the dimension for finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: what is the complete invariancy of the dimension for finite dimensional spaces? i am not familiar with that so is there a way to show bijection using basics?

Comment: @jamesblack two finite dimensional vectorial spaces are isomorphic $\iff$ have the same dimension, I’m sorry if I considered this basic.

Comment: sorry but now i recall that thank you for clarifying; just one more question-- we know the isomorphism is linear and injective, but why does that mean null vector lies in that and only the null vector?

Comment: @jamesblack what I meant is that if just $0$ lies in the intersection of $U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ considering them with the direct sum, (considering the isomorphism given between the spaces) only $\phi(0) = 0$ (thanks to linearity) will lie in $U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ considered as $U_{1} + U_{2}$

Comment: i am really sorry but i am more confused now by the wording, do you mean (thanks to injectivity) so only 0 maps to 0 in the kernel? I still do not really get how if we know it is linear and injective mapping, then only null vector lies in that section--can you expand/edit that specific part in your answer? thank you

Comment: @jamesblack take the isomorphism $\phi$ between $U_{1} + U_{2}$ and $U_{1} \bigoplus U_{2}$, $0$ is a vector in $U_{1} \cap U_{2}$, now take $v \ne 0 \in U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ and appy $\phi$, where's the contraddiction ?

Comment: it is no longer injective, correct? so thats the contradiction--but where does linearity come into play? thanks again

Comment: @jamesblack Correct, seems you’re right, I will edit that part

Comment: sorry, just to clarify, does linearity matter here? what would happen if it was not linear? out of curiosity

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the short exact sequence
\begin{alignat}4
0 &\longrightarrow{} & U_1\cap U_2 &\longrightarrow {}& U_1\otimes U_2 &\longrightarrow {} & U_1+U_2  &\longrightarrow  0 \\
&& u&\longmapsto &(u,-u) \\
&&&&(u_1,u_2)&\longmapsto &u_1+u_2
\end{alignat}